How can I use firebaseServerApp on a local emulator suite?
I am trying to build a web app using Next.js (App Router) on firebase. First, I am testing FrendlyEats, which is provided as a sample.
In this project, we are using FirebaseServerApp so that we can also authenticate on the server side using Service Worker. It works fine under the actual project environment, but not on the emulator.
The server side process does not seem to connect to the emulator, so I tried to run connectAuthEmulator, but it does not work correctly with the following error.
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/emulator-config-failed).
Setting the environment variable (FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST) did not help.
Please tell me how to get FirebaseServerApp to work correctly on the emulator environment.

Have you managed to fix it?

Whenever you use getAuthenticatedAppForUser, you need to connect the emulator. For example, my database calls look like this:
 // post to DB
  const { app, currentUser } = await getAuthenticatedAppForUser()
  const db = getFirestore(app)

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "development") {
    connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "127.0.0.1", 8080)
  }

